# How can I get NVDA and JAWS to read out the Hans Hillen datepicker correctly in Chrome in forms mode?

Tags: google-chrome, datepicker, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, nvda

A while ago, a fellow named Hans Hillen created some accessible versions of the jQuery UI controls. The popup version of [his accessible jQuery UI datepicker](http://hanshillen.github.io/jqtest/#goto_datepicker) has been implemented in a prototype I'm reviewing for WCAG 2.0 compliance, and the popup version of the date picker is not behaving well in Chrome.

The basics of the popup version of the date picker is this: focus on the input, then press down to focus on the date picker itself. You can then browse it from there using your arrow keys, or page up/down to skip months, etc.

In Firefox and IE, as you navigate the date cells, NVDA and JAWS will happily read out the date numbers and row/column positions.

In Chrome, for every single cell, NVDA reads out "cell", and JAWS reads out "contain controls", and that's it — no numbers or anything, no actually reading out the cell's contents. I've reproduced this reliably on a Windows Server 2008 machine with both NVDA and JAWS, and on a Windows 8.1 machine with NVDA (no JAWS available to test with on that one).

When I take NVDA out of forms mode and into virtual cursor mode (i.e. <kbd>NVDA</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>), it'll read out the cell contents just fine again, but then the keyboard controls don't function. Taking JAWS out of forms mode (<kbd>numpad +</kbd>) makes the datepicker a different sort of unintelligible.

How can I get NVDA and JAWS to read out the dates correctly in Chrome whilst in forms mode? I am looking for solutions from those who have dealt with this issue. If minimal sections of the datepicker code can be changed, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

You should give up because aria-activedescendant methodology, used in combination with the grid role does not work on most browser-AT combinations. Last time I tested it, it only worked with Firefox and NVDA on Windows. I have not tested it for about a year though.

Comment: An instruction to give up based on inconclusive information is not helpful to me. It seems support has improved, as it now works in more combinations. This will be more valuable if it actually demonstrates Chrome definitely does not support this feature. A great answer to this question will actually suggest an alternative handling in Chrome.

Comment: you mean other than, rewrite the datepicker? Because that is the alternative. If you want to know how to make it work, I can tell you but it involves a major re-write. You can see a rough prototype of one that works everywhere here http://dylanb.github.io/datepicker/datepicker.html

Comment: If the answer is "Chrome doesn't support the critical features and there is no way to do it other than with a major rewrite", and that answer is well cited, that is an acceptable answer. However, your answer is not cited, it is difficult to prove a negative, and I believe you are being overly pessimistic in your response here. Usually the "there is no solution" thing is proved by a question simply not acquiring a good answer, _or_ actual solid demonstration.

Comment: It is possible to get a date picker to work as my example states. However, I don't think it is possible to get the Hans Hillen datepicker to work - which is what your question asked - without a major re-write. Perhaps you should ask a better question if what you are asking for is alternatives. Another alternative http://whatsock.com/modules/aria_calendar_module/demo.htm

Comment: I am not asking for alternative datepickers, and that would be off topic for SO. I am asking for responses from people who have had experience attempting to get the Hans Hillen datepicker to work in Chrome, and what worked for them in getting it working. I can imagine _minor_ rewrites, such as also playing with focus, and am pursuing these options, but some of them may come out clunky or not be the best way. So I am requesting experience-based solutions. There is no other question I need to ask, I am just requesting that if you want to prove I need to give up, do it with solid citation.

Comment: Wait let me see, your first reaction was to downvote my answer and now you want me to continue helping you? Follow my links, read the code, good luck!

Comment: That isn't a request you keep helping me, it's me telling you my standard here for an acceptable answer. Yours doesn't meet it at present. This is not a personal issue, nor plea for assistance, this is answer quality evaluation. You are invited to improve your answer as a natural effect of how stack exchange works, but you have no obligation to accept and do so.

Comment: You could have asked nicely for more evidence before you down-voted. Remember, we all do this for free. Respect and thanks, extends beyond Stackoverflow...

Comment: Very good answer. Nothing to add. This answer deserves the bounty.